# Assertion failed when using pyswip

Tags: python, prolog

I have just installed pyswip and I was testing if it is working correctly but I always get this error: Assertion failed: 0, file /home/swipl/src/swipl-devel/src/pl-fli.c, line 2637

I was using this example code:

```
from pyswip import Prolog
prolog = Prolog()
prolog.assertz("father(michael,john)")
```

I am using windows 10 python 3.11.1 and I have swipl in the path.
I tested in WSL ubuntu and get the same error.

Knowing why this error happen and solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced a similar issue when getting a neurosymbolic model called DeepProbLog to run on my Windows. It'd be helpful to know which version of swipl and pyswip you have.

I personally use

- swipl version 8.4.2 for Windows 64 bits (https://www.swi-prolog.org/download/stable?show=all) \
- fork the pyswip provided by the repo in DeepProbLog `pip install git+https://github.com/ML-KULeuven/pyswip`

If you want to use WSL Ubuntu, you can keep reading DeepProbLog's github page as they also provide commands on working with Prolog in Linux.

Comment: Thank you! That works to me. I was using 9.0.4. I have installed 8.4.2 and work fine. Thanks

Comment: UPDATE: This issue has resurfaced in 2023. The fix is to use master instead of the default version indexed by pip - `pip install git+https://github.com/yuce/pyswip@master#egg=pyswip`